# Scraping information from specific remote site PHP

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape information using PHP from this site, however the information I'm looking for seems to be generated through Javascript or similar. I would be greateful for any suggestions on what approach to take!

This is the remote site that I'm trying to fetch data from: http://www.riksdagen.se/sv/webb-tv/video/debatt-om-forslag/yrkestrafik-och-taxi_H601TU11

The page contains a video and beneith the headline "Anförandelista" there are a number of names/links to individual time spots in the video.

I want to use PHP to automatically fetch the names and links in this list and store it in a database. However, this information is not included in the HTML source and thus I fail to retreive it.

Any ideas on how I can remotely access the information using an automated script? Or in which direction I should look for a solution? Any pointers are very much appreciated.

Comment: In order to do so, you would need software that could interpret and run JS code, as such PHP will only bring back the same source you see if you right clicked on the page and opted to show source. Google and other search engines do this for pages that are create client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this info as a json response from the API call the page makes. I don't know PHP, yet, but a quick Google shows handling json is possible and fairly straightforward. I give an example python script at the bottom.

The API call is this

http://www.riksdagen.se/api/videostream/get/H601TU11

It returns json as follows (just an excerpt shown. The json includes the speech as well):

[image]

Explore full json response [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f9b484e687b244eb99445e6a9fbd14b4).

---

**PHP**

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097711/how-would-i-scrape-this-json-info-using-php-and-mysql) you could start with something like:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.riksdagen.se/api/videostream/get/H601TU11'));
```

---

**Example python if wanted:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://www.riksdagen.se/api/videostream/get/H601TU11').json()    
results = []

for item in r['videodata'][0]['speakers']:
    start = item['start']
    duration = item['duration']
    speaker = item['text']
    row = [speaker, start, duration]
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Speaker', 'Start', 'Duration'])
print(df)
```

---

**Example output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the information loaded by JS using just PHP solution. Curl, file_get_contents and similar options will only get the server response for you, they will not execute JS as it is client side script.

For that you will need to use a headless browser (there are multiple to choose from: Chromium, Google Chrome with it's new headless mode or Selenium web driver are just few of the most popular ones)